# Change color of a component when clicking down and up

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I designed a component like "Tile" and I need to change the color when clicking down or up.
How can I do this?

Comment: change Color in own implementation of WM_LBUTTONDOWN / WM_LBUTTONUP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the procedures MouseDown() and MouseUp() introduced in TControl to set the color of your component.
If your component does not have a color property you will need to override the Paint procedure.

```
type
  TMyComp = Class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    FColor: TColor;
  protected
    // ....
    Procedure Paint; override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
      override;
  End;

implementation

{ TMyComp }

procedure TMyComp.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if Button = mbLeft then
  begin
    FColor := clRed;
    invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyComp.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if Button = mbLeft then
  begin
    FColor := clLime;
    invalidate;
  end;

end;

procedure TMyComp.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  // ...
  Canvas.Brush.Color := FColor;
  Canvas.FillRect(BoundsRect);
  // ....
end;
```

Comment: Instead of handling the `WM_...` messages directly, you should override the virtual `MouseDown()` and `MouseUp()` methods.  Let the framework handle the messages for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, I felt free to edit my answer using your suggestion.